# WSO2 ESB VFS Transport - Expects SOAP envelope

Tags: wso2, vfs, wso2-esb

I am trying to do a FTP based integration using WSO2 ESB. I am able to transfer files from one FTP location to another using VFS transport. But WSO2 ESB expects soap envelope inside the file am transferring.

This logic will not suit in case if Am transferring an image.

How to transfer the image/files with non soap envelope using VFS transport ?

Below error occurs if I transfer any file without soap envelope:

```
    [2013-06-07 14:01:31,314] ERROR - VFSTransportListener Error processing File URI
 : ftp://isova1:admin@10.208.29.144/isova.png
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8
 start byte 0x89 (at char #1, byte #-1)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.jav
a:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelo
pe(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSO
APModelBuilder.java:154)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBui
lder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder
(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLB
uilderFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java
:55)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFS
TransportListener.java:558)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirec
tory(VFSTransportListener.java:312)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTranspo
rtListener.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTranspo
rtListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.
run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(Native
WorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExec
utor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x89 (at c
har #1, byte #-1)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:625
)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:994)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNext(StreamScanner.java:754)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.ja
va:1977)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1114)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStr
eamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWra
pper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStr
eamReaderWrapper.java:225)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuild
er.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.jav
a:214)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x89 (at ch
ar #1, byte #-1)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidInitial(UTF8Reader.java:303)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:189)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:87)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.
java:57)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:988)
        ... 23 more
```

Regards
Guru
@gnanagurus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely occurs because the right `ContentType` of the VFS transport is not used.

When transferring binary data, use this:

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/octet-stream</parameter>
```

I just tried it on WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 and it worked fine for a png file, while using `text/plain` for the value of the `transport.vfs.ContentType` parameter was throwing the same exception as you described.

Check out the Synapse VFS service parameters [here](http://synapse.apache.org/transports.html#Transport_listener).